# PHP Multidimensional Array - Using Part of the Data

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

Quick Question:

I have the following array (multidimensional):

```
    Array ( 
        [preorder] => 0 
        [data] => Array ( 
             [0] => 03:00:00 
             [1] => 03:15:00 
             [2] => 03:30:00 
             [3] => 03:45:00 
             [4] => 04:00:00 
             [5] => 04:15:00 
             [6] => 04:30:00 
             [7] => 04:45:00 
             [8] => 05:00:00 
             ) 
      )
```

How, if possible do I use a foreach to get the options from the [data] subarray. So forexample if I were to write in PHP:

```
foreach($arrayname as $key=>$data) {
    echo $data[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

But this doesn't seem to work. I know how to do this if each item in the array is set as say 'time_slot' or something, but I'm not entirely sure how this could work?

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As `$arrayname['data']` is an array you can apply `foreach` function to it:

```
foreach($arrayname['data'] as $key=>$data) {
    echo "Key = " . $key ." and value = " . $data . "<br>\n";
}
```

Comment: Right on, before you were iterating through the containing array when you really wanted was to be iterating through the sub-array.

Comment: Thanks so much. I can't believe I couldn't work that out. Working through til 5:30am clearly isn't great for the mental abilities! haha